Recursion problem that makes an inverse of any number
Why in this code when put inv as global variable the function is working correctly (return the inverse of a number), but when make it local returns 4 (if N = 1234)?
I thought in this case it will return 1 in case of N = 1234.
 int inv = 0; // here it is global

 int inverse(int N){ 
    if(N == 0)
        return 0;

    int remainder = N % 10 ; 
    
    inv = inv*10 + remainder;

    inverse(N / 10);

    printf("%d ",inv);
    return inv;
}

int main() { 
    int N = 12345;
    int inv = inverse(N);
    printf("==> %d",inv);
}


Actual [mcve] would be in order here.

Note: don't use gobal variables.

If you're using a local variable, the issue lies in this code:
    int inv = inv*10 + remainder;

    inverse(N / 10);

The value of inv would not change after calling the inverse method below it since the value is in a local method scope and cannot transfer to another method.
Global variable on the other hand works because all instances of inverse share the same value in the global scope.
I'd recommend to change the global variable into a parameter that can be passed into recursive calls:
int inverse(int N, int inv) { 
  if(N == 0)
    return inv;

  int remainder = N % 10 ; 
  inv = inv * 10 + remainder;

  return inverse(N / 10, inv);
}

int main() { 
  int N = 12345;
  int inv = inverse(N, 0);
  printf("==> %d", inv);
  return 0;
}


You need neither a global nor a parameter value.
The point is to understand that you can decompose a number by repeated division and remainder.
  123 % 10 --> 3
  123 / 10 --> 12

  12 % 10 --> 2
  12 / 10 --> 1

  1 % 10 --> 1
  1 / 10 --> 0

You can compose a number by repeated multiplication and addition.
  (((1 * 10) + 2) * 10) + 3 --> 123

Now we can consider the order in which we handle single digits:

When decomping we get the digits in least-significant to most-significant order
When composing we add digits in most-significant to least-significant order.

The very fact that these orderings are inverse suggests a recursive construct:



decompose
digit
compose




123 → 12
3
0  → 3


12  → 1
2
3  → 32


1   → 0
1
32 → 321



The purpose of the homework question is twofold:

demonstrate understanding of composing and decomposing a number
demonstrate understanding of recursive constructs

We can understand the recursive construct as repeating something to take apart a list (decompose the number) AND to put a list together (compose a number).
You already have the recursive decompose state understood:

if the number is zero, we’re done
otherwise, split off a digit and repeat with the remaining digits

The question you need to answer is... what do I do with that digit I just split off? Right now you are simply printing it.
Hint: The order you do things matters. Do I print before or after recursion? How does that affect my printout?
Can I get rid of the print and use the value returned by the function itself to build a new number that I can return?
